# How can we explain the File system permissions in Unix?

Tags: unix, terminal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Modification of files with 777 permissions but not with 755 permissions?](https://superuser.com/questions/20457/modification-of-files-with-777-permissions-but-not-with-755-permissions)

In Unix , we have a file permissions which can be changed with chmod command . But applying the permissions are always confusable for beginners . If anyone can explain it with the simple terms , would be very useful.

Comment: Closed as duplicate since the answer points to the duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave a somewhat detailed explanation [here](https://superuser.com/questions/20457/modification-of-files-with-777-permissions-but-not-with-755-permissions). [This page](http://www.zzee.com/solutions/unix-permissions.shtml) is also very in depth, I recommend you give it a read.

Now that I think about it, a permissions calculator was the first program I made with a GUI. I'll try to find it.

Comment: i made already one http://desktop.google.com/plugins/i/unixchmod_cumakt.html?hl=en

Comment: Nice, a gadget too! Mines a bit smaller :) http://rapidshare.com/files/277520186/Permissions.7z brings back memories.

Comment: @John T  This seems to be some sort of ".exe" file.  *file* reports it is for something called "MS Windows".

Comment: Yeah any GUI programs I made when starting out were for Windows. I didn't know much about toolkits like Qt and programming even a simple "Hello World" for X was a painstaking process.

Comment: Your answer on that previous question pretty much sums this question up as a dupe.

Answer (score 2):

Use the famous Online CHMOD Calculator, it works great and is VERY interactive:

http://www.onlineconversion.com/html_chmod_calculator.htm